# Challenge: A good, swift kick

Tags: building, challenge

#### Hey everyone, this is Bricks.SE's first challenge question!

Context: On other sites, you sometimes see a question made specifically for the purposes of getting a lot of good ideas, the checkmark given to the best answer.

But with bricks, it gets even *more* fun. A certain challenge may put not only your knowledge, but also your building skill. So it won't work like Oveflow, Codegolf, or WB. It might be even *better.*

So, the question today is: How would you make a non-technic structure, at least 2 feet tall, that can withstand a full kick? Include pictures!

Rules:

Non-technic means that the build must have less than 50% technic pieces.

The build must be on a flat surface, and cannot be "dug in."

"Withstand" entails that no pieces are removed.

If no pictures are given, the description must be thorough, for replication.

The bricks may be LEGO, BIONICLE, Mega Bloks, KRE-O, or other clone brands, but not DUPLO, QUATRO, K'NEX, or Znap.

The answer with the most votes in a week that provably solves the problem will be the winner.

Comment: I'm completely in support of having challenges on the site. However, I don't expect most of us have access to a baseball pitching machine. Is there possibly some other way we could qualify the best answer? Also, try and be as specific as possible on the rules, "How deep can it be?", "Are large pieces like Duplo & Quatro" allowed?", "What do you define to be the 'best' answer (Fewest Bricks, Strongest, Smallest) etc...

Comment: I'm not as in-tune with the specifics of challenges in general on Stack Exchange sites, but I have to thank you for apparently pioneering the tag, as I was just today thinking of a challenge I could use help with.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I appreciate it. Yeah, its always risky, the first introduction of a challenge, sometimes it bombs and then the person proposing it gets downvoted and closevoted to the SE underworld. :)

Comment: I am not at all against challenges like this (I am all for it in fact) or have anything against your implementation, but adding new aspects like this to an SE site is usually proposed and discussed in meta first.  That way the entire community can have a say and discuss it together.  Remember, SE is a community run network.  *(If this was already brought up on meta, please kindly ignore this comment.  I searched for "challenge" and looked through all your meta posts and didn't find anything.)*

Comment: We did bring it up in meta, I will see I'd I can find the post.

Comment: Are you really expecting me to kick my LEGO MOC? Oh, I just realize how old this post is.